# Dump the output of internal vim command into buffer

Tags: command-line, buffers

How do I dump an internal vim command (not shell command) into a new buffer?

For example, I want to dump a listing of all plugins into `:enew` from `:scriptnames` so that I can search it.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/2573021/6266107. Great explanations,.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can use `:redir` to redirect the output to a variable, register, or file. Example of redirecting to the unnamed register:

```
:redir @">|silent scriptnames|redir END|enew|put
```

Alternatively Tim Pope's [scriptease.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-scriptease) provides the `:Scriptnames` command which will load `:scriptnames` into the quickfix list and `:copen`.

If you find yourself redirecting many commands you may want to wrap up this up in a command:

```
command! -nargs=+ -complete=command Redir let s:reg = @@ | redir @"> | silent execute <q-args> | redir END | new | pu | 1,2d_ | let @@ = s:reg
```

Now you can use the `:Redir` command to redirect the output to a new buffer. e.g. `:Redir scriptnames` or `:Redir ls`.

#### Vim 8+

Vim 8 ships with the new `execute()` function. You can use the `execute()` function to instead of `:redir` to capture ex-command output.

```
 :enew|pu=execute('scriptnames')
```

For more help see:

```
:h :redir
:h :silent
:h :scriptnames
:h :enew
:h :put
:h execute()
```

Comment: What does `END` mean?

Comment: It stops redirecting the output to the register so you can have regular output again.

Comment: `:redir END` tells Vim to end redirecting messages. See `:h :redir`

Comment: To execute an external command and capture its output in a Vim variable, use system(). 

:let hostname = system('hostname')

Answer (score 8):

For completeness, I want to present this awesome functions that I collected (stole) from [romainl](https://gist.github.com/romainl/eae0a260ab9c135390c30cd370c20cd7)

```
" redirect the output of a Vim or external command into a scratch buffer
function! Redir(cmd)
  if a:cmd =~ '^!'
    execute "let output = system('" . substitute(a:cmd, '^!', '', '') . "')"
  else
    redir => output
    execute a:cmd
    redir END
  endif
  tabnew
  setlocal nobuflisted buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe noswapfile
  call setline(1, split(output, "\n"))
  put! = a:cmd
  put = '----'
endfunction
command! -nargs=1 Redir silent call Redir(<f-args>)
```

This will take normal or system command output and put it in a new tab. Feel free to change the line `tabnew` to `vnew` or `new` etc.

(`new` and `vnew` are alternatives to `split` and `vsplit` as the output would otherwise be printed in your current file)

Comment: the link to @ romainl's gist https://gist.github.com/romainl/eae0a260ab9c135390c30cd370c20cd7

Answer (score 6):

To understand easily, I splitted full command into small sub commands:

1. Redirect to register "
2. Execute the actual command. Go till the end of output.
3. Stop redirect.
4. Open new buffer and paste from register "

   ```
   :redir @"
   :map
   :redir END
   :enew|put
   ```

Answer (score 5):

There's also the [bufferize.vim](https://github.com/AndrewRadev/bufferize.vim) plugin:

```
:Bufferize scriptnames
```

which is basically a packaged version of the accepted answer (using `:redir`) and may be more convenient for some.

Answer (score 0):

the best solution is with the asyncrun plugin (requiring vim8+):
https://github.com/skywind3000/asyncrun.vim

```
:AsyncRun -mode=term -pos=bottom -rows=15 -cols=40 -focus=0 pwd
```

will open a 15 rows terminal at bottom, run the linux command pwd and display the output there.

read its wiki for more info.

Comment: The OP is looking to capture the output of a *Vim* command, not a shell command.

Comment: Thanks, came up while searching for exactly this... agree this is _"wrong"_ re answering  OP's q...