# Why does the syntax foldmethod not work even though syntax highlighting works?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, folding, filetype-javascript

Started editing a JavaScript file, did `:set filetype=javascript` (correct syntax highlighting kicked in), then `set foldmethod=syntax`, and naively expected that folding should automatically work, but that's not the case. What am I missing?

`:help fold-syntax` states:

> SYNTAX                        *fold-syntax*
>
> A fold is defined by syntax items that have the "fold" argument.
> |:syn-fold|
>
> The fold level is defined by nesting folds.  The nesting of folds is
> limited with 'foldnestmax'.
>
> Be careful to specify proper syntax syncing.  If this is not done
> right, folds may differ from the displayed highlighting.  This is
> especially relevant when using patterns that match more than one line.
> In case of doubt, try using brute-force syncing:
> `:syn sync fromstart`

Found the files affecting the rendering of the buffer using `:scriptnames` (with the help of [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/686241/how-do-i-tell-what-syntax-file-is-being-used) and [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/8378/dump-the-output-of-internal-vim-command-into-buffer)) - the list has 98 files, including at line 75: [`vim-8.2.3451/share/vim/vim82/syntax/javascript.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/c54f347d63bcca97ead673d01ac6b59914bb04e5/runtime/syntax/javascript.vim) (linked to the Vim source code entry as it is an exact match).

The only place there is a `fold` word is in this block, but too much of a novice to make sense of `:help syn-fold`...

```
if exists("javaScript_fold")
    syn match   javaScriptFunction  "\<function\>"
    syn region  javaScriptFunctionFold  start="\<function\>.*[^};]$" end="^\z1}.*$" transparent fold keepend

    syn sync match javaScriptSync   grouphere javaScriptFunctionFold "\<function\>"
    syn sync match javaScriptSync   grouphere NONE "^}"

    setlocal foldmethod=syntax
    setlocal foldtext=getline(v:foldstart)
else
    syn keyword javaScriptFunction  function
    syn match   javaScriptBraces       "[{}\[\]]"
    syn match   javaScriptParens       "[()]"
endif
```

Comment: You need to set the variable `javaScript_fold` before you edit a JavaScript file: `:let g:javaScript_fold = 1`

Comment: Try adding `let g:javaScript_fold = 1` to your vimrc file? Let me know if that works for you, I can turn it into an answer then... (Though I see Heptite got there first, so I'll leave it to them to post it as an answer.)

Comment: Yep, that was it. Feel like an idiot, but at least it works..:) Thank you to both of you! (.. and if an answer is posted, will accept it right away.)