# Is there a keybinding that allows to scroll through the status line?

Tags: statusline, scrolling

I was wondering if it was possible to scroll (left or right) along the status line so that the content (which could not be displayed due to the size of the window) could be seen.

Perhaps there is a key combination that allows this, something like `Control+E` and `Control+Y` (key combinations that allow you to move through the content of the file).

Complete statusline

[image: Complete statusline]

Incomplete statusline

[image: Incomplete statusline]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Vi&Vim SE. No such scrolling feature unfortunately. Best bet is probably to figure out what expression or variable is being displayed there (check `:set statusline?` output) and then create convenient mapping that evaluates that expression and echos it in the message/command-line area (it won't be truncated there).

Comment: If this is about seeing the full path of your current file and you do not need to see this all the time, see [How can I see the full path of the current file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/104/how-can-i-see-the-full-path-of-the-current-file).