# Get path to parent directory and use it in a nnoremap command?

Tags: key-bindings, vimscript

Say I have a `nnoremap` and I want to pass the path of parent directory of current file to it, so the command can use this information. I have read this answer: [How can I see the full path of the current file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/104/how-can-i-see-the-full-path-of-the-current-file) but Still don't know how to do it?

I just found that `%` almost do the job, but it returns path to current file.

Answer (score 1):

OK, after some try-and-error I resolved this problem. To get the path to
parent dir:

```
%:p:h
```

Notice that the `:p` is needed to get the full path, without it you might end up with   nothing, i.e. it's possible you cannot find the parent folder.

For example, my usage:

```
nnoremap <nowait><silent> <Tab>
                        \ :Fern %:h -drawer -width=36 -toggle -reveal=%<CR>
```

As you can see it is used directly inside the command, without any parentheses, single/double quotes, curly braces around it.

Comment: You can also use `expand()` when you need this in a context where it is not automatically expanded